# Angular how to use slicePipe in the new @for loop

Tags: angular

How can you use the slicePipe with the new @for syntax in Angular?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'slice-list-pipe',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let i of collection | slice : 1 : 3">{{ i }}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class SlicePipeListComponent {
  collection: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Have you even tried to use it in same way? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@for` syntax supports using the pipes and its application is the same as in the `*ngFor`. An important point is you must add the `track` expression in the `@for` syntax.

> The mandatory *track* expression allows Angular to identify individual elements that have been moved within the iterated collection.

Reference: [What’s new in Angular 17? (New Syntax for Control Flow in Templates section)](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/whats-new-in-angular-17/)

```
<ul>
  @for (i of collection | slice : 1 : 3; track $index) {
    <li>{{ i }}</li>
  }
</ul>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rfjnef?file=src%2Fmain.ts)